# app in Android Studio that is extremely slow when changing from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an app in Android Studio that is extremely slow when changing from one activity to another. The first activity is a recyclerview where some values are entered (a variable number that depends on a parameter) in edittexts. When I enter up to 12 values, the activity changes well, but for a higher number of values it is extremely slow, the more the more values I enter, the more so. I have also tried putting the edittext with a for loop instead of a recyclerview and the result is the same. I've checked the ram and it doesn't seem full.
this is the code for the first activity:

```
public class pantallaDeInicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Bien[] Input_Array;
    public RecyclerView recycler;
    public Button siguiente;
    public ArrayList<Bien> input = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Bien> ia = new ArrayList<>();
    public int tamañoArray;
    ArrayList<Bien> bienes= new ArrayList<>();
    public String[] alNombres;
    public double[]  alValores;
    public String[]nombres;
    public double []valores;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_de_inicio);

        siguiente= findViewById(R.id.siguiente);
        recycler= findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        //recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        tamañoArray=Integer.parseInt(introducirPrimerosDatos.numeroBienes.getText().toString());
        Input_Array = new Bien[tamañoArray];
        nombres=new String[tamañoArray];
        valores=new double[tamañoArray];

        adapter a= new adapter(tamañoArray);
        recycler.setAdapter(a);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter ad = (adapter) recycler.getAdapter();
                alNombres = ad.getNombres();
                alValores = ad.getValores();

                Intent intent = new Intent(pantallaDeInicio.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombres", alNombres);
                intent.putExtra("valores", alValores);
                intent.putExtra("tamañoArray", tamañoArray);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is the layout code for this activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/siguiente" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/siguiente"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Siguiente" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the adapter code, for the recylcerview:

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.CampoViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> valores = new ArrayList<>();

    public adapter(int numCampos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numCampos; i++) {
            nombres.add("");
            valores.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    public void actualizarNombre(int posicion, String nuevoNombre) {
        nombres.set(posicion, nuevoNombre);
    }

    public void actualizarValor(int posicion, double nuevoValor) {
        valores.set(posicion, nuevoValor);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CampoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_campo, parent, false);
        return new CampoViewHolder(view,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CampoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nombres.size(); // o valores.size(), ambos deben tener el mismo tamaño
    }

    public String[] getNombres() {
        String[] nombresArray = new String[nombres.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
            nombresArray[i] = nombres.get(i);
        }
        return nombresArray;
    }

    public double[] getValores() {
        double[] valoresArray = new double[valores.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) {
            valoresArray[i] = valores.get(i);
        }
        return valoresArray;
    }

    static class CampoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText etNombre;
        EditText etValor;
        adapter adapter;
        CampoViewHolder(View itemView,adapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            etNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            etValor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor);
            this.adapter = adapter;
            etNombre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    adapter.actualizarNombre(getAdapterPosition(), s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            });

            etValor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                            adapter.actualizarValor(getAdapterPosition(), Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
                        } else {
                            // No actualices el valor en el adaptador cuando la cadena esté vacía
                        }

                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            });
        }

        void bind(int position) {
            etNombre.setText(adapter.getNombres()[position]);

            double valorDouble = adapter.getValores()[position];
            if (valorDouble != 0.0) {
                etValor.setText(String.valueOf(valorDouble));
            } else {
                etValor.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I provide the oncreate code (for the second activity) because the rest of the activity is very long and it is true that it is very heavy, but the heavy code is only executed once the calculate button is pressed, but not when the activity is created.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    nHerederos=Integer.parseInt(introducirPrimerosDatos.numeroHerederos.getText().toString());
    k = Integer.parseInt(introducirPrimerosDatos.numeroBienes.getText().toString());


    String []nombres = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("nombres");
    double []valores = getIntent().getExtras().getDoubleArray("valores");
    int tamañoArray = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tamañoArray");

    Input_Array= new Bien[tamañoArray];
    //Log.i("hola","que tal");
    for(int i=0;i<tamañoArray;i++)
    {
        Bien b =new Bien();
        b.setNombre(nombres[i]);
        b.setValor(valores[i]);
        Log.i("hola",nombres[i]);
        Input_Array[i]=b;

    }

    for(int i=0;i<nHerederos;i++)
    {
        listaHerederos.add("Heredero "+String.valueOf(i));
    }

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setText("Calcular");
    //txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    tableLayout= findViewById(R.id.table);

    for (int l = 1; l <= k; l++) {
        nCombTotales += nCombinaciones(k, l);
    }

    nCombCombTotalesTotales = nCombinacionesBD(nCombTotales, nHerederos);
    combinaciones = new Bien[(int) nCombTotales][k];

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count =1;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn:

                    new MyTask().execute(10);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the app in physical device or an emulator? Also can you check your stacktrace for any skipped frame, provide  your stacktrace here.

Comment: Provide code from the second activity. Probably it's doing some heavy task in onCreate

Comment: you where right. There was a heavy task in the second activity. I moved it to the onclick event and now works fine. Thanks.

Comment: So the problem occurs at app run-time not in the IDe? If yes please remove the Android Studio tag as the IDE has nothing to do with the run-time problem of your app. It is just the IDE.